# how to create a rewrite rule for this type of URL, For myurl.com/user=john

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have URL which is some what like this `myurl.com?user=john` what i want to know is that how can i create a re write rule which will translate my pages to something like this

```
john.myurl.com
```

i have some thing like this in my **htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  welcome.php?user=john

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.myFolder
RewriteRule (.*)  welcome.php?user=%1
```

Comment: No. You don't want to do this, trust me. Even with Wildcard DNS this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:can you point out what should i do?

Comment: You should just stick with pretty url's. `myurl.com/user/john` as opposed to `myurl.com?user=john`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: can you tell me why is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: please tell me as i am totally blank regarding usage of wildcards, never used it.